# How do i get The dropdown to have the value of the sub cat and custom fields

Tags: search, forms

I Have the files 
searchform.php 
search.php
adv-search.php that conect the dropdown categories  and the code that show the dropdown is...

```
enter code here$args = array(                                           
                     'child_of' => $current_term->term_id,
'taxonomy' => $current_term->taxonomy,
'hide_empty' => 0,
'hierarchical' => true,
'depth'  => 0,
'title_li' => '',
    'show_option_all' => All,
    'hide_if_empty' => true,

                );
                wp_dropdown_categories($args);
```

Comment: Do you mean you want the dropdown to have the correct option selected for the current page?

Comment: Yes. the dropdown need to have the current page category.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to first setup a way to get the category of the current page. Maybe something using [get_the_category()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/) or similar. Then after you have done that you want to set the `selected` argument to the ID of the category you want to be selected. Right now you have it set to `-1`.

See the description of `selected` [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_categories).

Comment: Thank you Nick, I check that help me to find this solution but still need to display the sub cat and the custom fields.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You mean in the page content you need to display those items or how?